# Making an antlr4 parser rule that cannot have any skipped characters

Tags: c++, antlr4

I am trying to write an antlr4 grammar for a customized language which among its lexer rules originally contained the following:

```
PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
NUMBER: ('+'|'-')? [0-9]+ ;
COMMENT : '/*' (COMMENT|~'*'|('*' ~'/'))* '*/' -> skip ;
WS  : (' ' | '\t' | '\n') -> skip ;
```

The parser grammar contains, among other things, an arithmetic expression evaluator, and what I found is that using these lexer rules failed to parse the input '2-2' correctly, which should come out as `NUMBER` `MINUS` `NUMBER`, and instead just returned two `NUMBER` tokens.   I therefore broke out the unary + and - applications into it's own parser rule, as follows:

```
literal_number : NUMBER
    | '-' NUMBER
    | '+' NUMBER ;
```

And defined `NUMBER` simply as:

```
NUMBER: [0-9]+ ;
```

However, with this arrangement, the `literal_number` parser rule is being activated even if there is whitespace or comments between the plus and minus tokens and the number itself.  This should not be valid in parser contexts where I am expecting to see only an integer constant (which is actually anywhere other than when parsing arithmetic expressions).  I have another parser rule elsewhere in my parser grammar that handles unary negation already, so I do not need to replicate that in the `literal_number` parser rule anyways, so all I what I want is for the `literal_number` parser rule to refer only to places in the text where a real integer constant had been found.

How can I do this?   I have already looked at questions on stackoverflow pertaining to rules that are sensitive to whitespace, but I have not been able to figure out how to apply any of those solutions to my problem.

I'm not sure that this matters for my question, but my target language is c++, although I expect I may still be able to generalize from a java-specific example if one is offered.

EDIT:

The response that I've seen so far highlights an issue with my original comment which may have been ambiguous.  In my defense I had not wanted to complicate my original question with information that I did not immediately see as relevant, but in light of the response I've seen so far, I can now clearly see that it is.  I can only offer my apologies for this initial oversight.

In addition to the literal_number rule, I also have the following rule for expressions, which, in particular, has a rule allowing for negation.

```
expression : ID # look up value
    | literal_number # number
    | MINUS expression # negate
    | expression (STAR|SLASH) expression # multiply
    | expression (PLUS|MINUS) expression # add
    ;
```

So to that end, the expression `2-2` should evaluate as `literal_number (2) MINUS literal_number (2)`, `2--2` should evaluate as `literal_number (2) MINUS literal_number (-2)`, while `2-- 2` should evaluate as `literal_number (2) MINUS MINUS literal_number (2)`.

So basically, as I said originally, I only want the literal_number rule to be used at all when the NUMBER is by itself or MINUS and the NUMBER are side by side with no ignored tokens between them, but I cannot just  make `('+'|'-') [0-9]` a lexical rule for NUMBER without causing the problem I had in the first place.

Comment: Your lexer rules are ambiguous, rewrite your grammar to resolve - as a sign Vs operator in the parser not lexer. If you need the whitespace to matter, add a whitespace token.

Comment: If I must add an explicit whitespace token to be returned from the lexer in order to make the 'literal_number' parser rule sensitive to that, then I have to revise my language grammar to have (WS|COMMENT)* between every terminal, further complicating the language grammar.

Comment: Because, to put it plainly, they aren't the same, even if they might evaluate to the same thing at runtime.  Generally speaking,`-<ignored characters>1` conceptually represents a negated value that just happens to be constant, and only has meaning in the language inside of something like a general expression where the arithmetic operation of negation is permitted, not in other contexts where the grammar is expecting only to ever find constant values.